# process nodejs undefined into bindings.js with Electron project (and better-sqlite3)

Tags: node.js, sqlite, webpack, electron

I created a Electron.js project like that :

1. install node 14
2. install vue-cli
3. create template project vue with : vue create myproject
4. install electron wrapper like this : vue add electron builder
5. install better-sqlite3 library

And when I run this command : `npm run electron:serve`

I have an error into inspect of browser electron like this :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined
at Object.eval (bindings.js?dfc1:29)
at eval (bindings.js:223)
at Object../node_modules/bindings/bindings.js (chunk-vendors.js:142)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
at fn (app.js:151)
at eval (database.js?4c26:9)
at Object../node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js (chunk-vendors.js:59)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
at fn (app.js:151)
at eval (index.js?f4f1:2)
```

and if I enter into bindings.js code I can find where is the error :

```
nodePreGyp:
  'node-v' +
    process.versions.modules** +
```

The loader of this file don't know process env variable of nodejs.

- Why node js doesn't knowing it's process variable, it's strange ?
- If Electron to do well to start browser, the issue is around the renderer process ?
- But it seems to be better-sqlite3 module is concerned because error start with loading this library with webpack ?

there is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "electron-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/better-sqlite3": "^5.4.1",
    "better-sqlite3": "^7.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.11",
    "@types/electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "electron": "^9.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "spectron": "11.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.0.0-rc.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/typescript/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2020
    },
    "rules": {},
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)",
          "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"
        ],
        "env": {
          "mocha": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

If I comment code line with import better-sqlite3 I don't have the issue.

Can you tell me where is the problem or help me to more understand how fix this...

Thank you

Comment: Hello @darkomen. Did you solve the issue? How? I have a similar situation with another library, same error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has an origin from webpack auto managed by vue cli.

If you want to use better-sqlite3 library (or for similar issue) with vue and loading your project with webpack WRAPPED by vue into vue-cli, you need to add this into the vue.config.js

```
configureWebpack: {
    externals: {
        'better-sqlite3': 'commonjs better-sqlite3'
    },
},
```

**WARNING :** you can use vue-cli and webpack without this specific file into your project because vue-cli managed that for you. But if you want to more customize vue-cli you need to add manually this file (which merged with the base vue.config.js that hidden by vue-cli).